# AHK - prevent defined EndChar from executing as a key

Tags: autohotkey

Given the template .ahk file below:

```
    #NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
    ; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
    SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
    SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

    #Hotstring EndChars `n


::td:: //TODO - some string
```

1) I type "td"

2) I press enter

and the defined text is triggered. But "enter" as well, which takes me to the new line.

Desired behaviour:

1) I type "td"

2) I press enter

and the defined text is triggered **without** being taken to the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the single line like this:

```
:o:td:: //TODO - some string
```

Or you can add the following line to have it affect all the hotstrings in the file:

```
#Hotstring o
```

---

From the help files:

> O: Omit the ending character of auto-replace hotstrings when the
>   replacement is produced. This is useful when you want a hotstring to
>   be kept unambiguous by still requiring an ending character, but don't
>   actually want the ending character to be shown on the screen. For
>   example, if :o:ar::aristocrat is a hotstring, typing "ar" followed by
>   the spacebar will produce "aristocrat" with no trailing space, which
>   allows you to make the word plural or possessive without having to
>   backspace. Use O0 (the letter O followed by a zero) to turn this
>   option back off.